# Local host site redirect to live website in magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento-1.8

Localhost site redirect to live website in magento 1.8.1?

I cleared cache, deleted session and change  core_config_data: web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url still redirect to my live server?

Answer (score 0):

I delete all file in app/etc/module and download new file after working fine.